# How can we encourage editing poorly expressed questions rather than downvoting them?

Tags: discussion

There are occasionally questions which are on-topic and novel, but which are poorly written or poorly expressed. The question in itself is a good question for the stack exchange, but in the particular is riddled with typos, redundant sentences and words, misspellings, etc.

I've noticed that when this happens, I will often come across the question downvoted and ignored. No comments suggesting how to make it better, no attempts at an answer. This does not seem like the best way to improve the site.

[This can serve as an example](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/94276/can-a-catholic-priest-be-tied-to-a-single-parish-or-other-physical-church-his-en). I've edited this question to make it more clear and removed typos and spelling mistakes. It was a good question that was downvoted to negatives when I found it and totally ignored. It just needed some TLC.

How can we encourage this behavior of fixing good questions poorly expressed, and discourage the downvote-and-ignore?